# Filepath copied after find-file

Tags: emacs

When I open a file in Emacs, it somehow copies the file path into my clipboard. It's not a desired behavior. **How to turn it off?**

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1, build with Cocoa.

Comment: try `emacs -q`. Maybe it's your operating system that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step would be to know "who" is copying that into the clipboard.

Is the window system clipboard we are talking about?

If so, you can do

```lisp
(setq debug-on-error t)
(fset 'x-set-selection nil)
```

and then open a file. Hopefully the stack trace should give you a clue of what package is doing that.

Comment: Figured it out. It was me being silly expecting `M-backspace` shouldn't put them pathnames into the kill ring. Thanks for confirming it wasn't something specific of `find-file`.